# VB.NET- Validacion Combobox mediante ErrorProvider

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola buenas tardes a todos, junto con saludarlos queria consultarles, alguien ha usado el errorprovider en la validacion de un combobox?

tengo un boton que en el evento click solicita validar que se halla ingresado un valor en un textbox y que se seleccione un item del combobox, en mi botin tengo este codigo:

```
If Me.ValidateChildren And txtNombre.Text <> String.Empty And cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1) Then

            'ACCIONES A SEGUIR PORQUE SE PASO LA VALIDACION
            MsgBox("PASAMOS LAS VALIDACIONES")
        Else
            'FALLO LA VALIDACION DE LOS CONTROLES
            MsgBox("SE PRESENTARON ERRORES, FAVOR CORRIGALOS")

        End If
```

estoy usando el metodo validating del combobox para validar, en el cual uso este codigo:

```
If (cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex.Equals(0)) Then
    Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "")
Else
   Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "Seleccione Departamento")
End If
```

pero me arroja a cada rato que debo seleccionar un valor, es decir reconoce que no seleccione nada, pero cuando selecciono, me sigue arrojando el mismo error.

Saludos a todos y desde ya gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Si ya seleccionó solo debe hacer `Me.erpSoporte.Clear()`

Comment: lo habia probado y no me funciono...

Comment: Estoy viendo que tiene un validación un poco estraña solo no mostrará el `errorProvider` si el indice del combo es cero (0) según su validación

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está causando el "Error" es porque en tu comparación estas indicando que si tu index = 0 entonces No muestre el error, de caso contrario lo debe mostrar.

Cámbialo con esto a ver si te sirve

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles cmbDepartamento.Validating
    If cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1) Then
        Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "Seleccione Departamento")
    Else
        Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto `Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "")` de todos modos mostrará el icono del error sin mensaje, pienso que debe usar: `Me.erpSoporte.Clear()`

Comment: de esa manera pasa, pero pasa aun si no selecciono nada del combobox...

Comment: [En esta referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider) no usan el clear(), aunque podría llevarlo, en lo personal no lo he usado y me ha funcionado de forma correcta.

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid y si colocaste el -1 o lo comparaste con 0 ?

Comment: @SilvestreSilva donde hacer ese cambio? en el validatting del combo?

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid  si, para que no te confundas con los signos de comparación (<>) entonces edite la respuesta usando **.equals()**

Comment: creo que ahora si lo consegui, para cualquier consulta a futuro, lo deje asI, en el evento validating del combo:   If cmbDepartamento.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Me.erpSoporte.Clear()
        Else
            Me.erpSoporte.SetError(sender, "Seleccione Departamento")
        End If

Comment: Si te solucionó tu problema, considera aceptar la respuesta que te haya servido, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No programo en VB.NET pero creo que algo como esto podría funcionar.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Validating( sender As System.Object,  e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtNombre.Validating, cmbDepartamento.Validating
    Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    If ctl.Text = ""
        e.Cancel = True
        erpSoporte.SetError(ctl,"SE PRESENTARON ERRORES, FAVOR CORRIGALOS")
    End If
End Sub
```

Entonces lo puedes llamar:

```
erpSoporte.Clear()
If Me.ValidateChildren()
     ' continue aquí'
End If
```

Finalmente, si no quiere escribir todos los controles, puede hacer esto en la carga de formulario:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf(c) is TextBox or TypeOf(c) is ComboBox
        AddHandler c.Validating, AddressOf Me.TextBox_Validating
    End If
Next
```

Espero le sirva de ayuda.